# Managing profiles during release

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

I'm new of maven-release-plugin and I'm try to release my java web application for the first time. Now I'm able to tag the application, but I have some issues during the process.

I try to explain you in a better way. I'm working on a modular project:

```
|-- parent
    |-- model
        pom.xml
    |-- services
        pom.xml
    |-- rest
        pom.xml
    |-- web-app
        pom.xml
pom.xml
```

This is the parent's pom tagged:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>it.myCompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>model</module>
    <module>services</module>
    <module>rest</module>
    <module>web-app</module>
  </modules>

  <scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:svn://192.168.0.9/home/svn/myFolder/tags/myApp2.1.0/</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:svn://192.168.0.9/home/svn/myFolder/tags/myApp2.1.0/</developerConnection>
  </scm>

   <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>    
                <groupId>com.google.code.maven-scm-provider-svnjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-svnjava</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
            <providerImplementations>
                <svn>javasvn</svn>
            </providerImplementations>


            <goals>tomcat7:deploy</goals>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <!-- To launch embded tomcat server -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://192.168.0.21:8081/manager/text</url>
                <server>tomcat-devel</server>
            </configuration>    
    </plugin>     
</plugins>
</build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>Development</id>
            <properties>
                <db.driverClass>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</db.driverClass>
                <db.connectionURL>jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.12:1521:development</db.connectionURL>
                <db.username>myUser</db.username>
                <db.password>MyPass</db.password>
                <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
                <maven.javadoc.skip>true</maven.javadoc.skip>
            </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>Customer1</id>
            <properties>
                <db.driverClass>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</db.driverClass>
                <db.connectionURL>jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.13:1521:Customer1</db.connectionURL>
                <db.username>myUser</db.username>
                <db.password>MyPass</db.password>
                <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
                <maven.javadoc.skip>true</maven.javadoc.skip>
            </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>Customer2</id>
            <properties>
                <db.driverClass>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</db.driverClass>
                <db.connectionURL>jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.14:1521:Customer2</db.connectionURL>
                <db.username>myUser</db.username>
                <db.password>MyPass</db.password>
                <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
                <maven.javadoc.skip>true</maven.javadoc.skip>
            </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Instead this is the section of my persistence.xml contained within of the model project

```
<properties>
   <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="${db.driverClass}" />
   <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="${db.connectionURL}" />
   <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="${db.username}" />
   <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="${db.password}" />
</properties>
```

Now, since that I have some clients where install myApp, I try to execute

> mvn release:perform -P Customer1

but this not works, the  build process is not able to substitute the label    ${db.driverClass},${db.connectionURL},${db.username},${db.password} with the corrisponding values contained within the Customer1 profile.

And the problem recurs also with tomcat, since I  have to install myApp on different tomcat ( Customer1 has a own tomcat on 192.168.0.20 while Customer2 has a own tomcat on 192.168.0.21).

Any suggestion abuot this?
How can I fix it?

Comment: Where is your persistence.xml file located?

Comment: My persistence is content within the META-INF folder of model project, but my main concern is that I don't know if my way to do is the correct strategy for this situation, because I want to tag all projects (model,services,rest,web-app) and after tag action i want to deploy web-app on tomcat7 server. Is this the correct way to do?want to deploy web-app on tomcat7 server. Is this the correct way to do?